# VSTS - Copying files from remote server to the build server

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using VSTS as a build server, and while building I want to copy a specific file  from a remote server to the build server (so I can use the "*Publish Test Results*" with this file)

I tried to add the "*Copy Files Over SSH*" task, but it seems to only copy files from the local build server machine to the remote server. I need the exact opposite.

I can issue a command to the remote server (by ssh), using *scp* and *sshpass* but is there a more elegant way to do this? Is there a specific task that I can use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making an assumption: You're pushing tests to some remote servers, running them, and you want to retrieve and publish the test results.

I'd use a multi-phase build in conjunction with Deployment Groups for this.

- Phase 1 (Agent phase): Build, push tests to whatever servers need to have the tests
- Phase 2 (Deployment Group phase) Run the tests, publish the results.

Comment: You're right.. I'm pushing the tests to some remote server and running the tests from there.. But the tests output an XML file which the "Publish Test Results" task needs to use. To use this task I need to somehow copy the "test results" file to the build server.. How can I do that?

Comment: My answer explains how to do this without copying files.

Comment: But to publish the results, I still need the file from the remote server.. What am I missing?

Comment: Deployment groups run on the target servers instead of relying on a process being invoked from a build machine.

Comment: How do I add tasks to the deployment group? Is there some good guide for these phases?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/phases?view=vsts&tabs=designer

Comment: almost my scenarios is same, I wan to to take backup before release get started on remote machine folder, how I can do this?